# #Error# C4703 Potential unitialized local pointer variable 'pBelowMask' , 'pMask' , and 'pAboveMask' used

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

> Error C4703 Potential initialized local pointer variable 'pBelowMask' , 'pMask' ,and 'pAboveMask' used

I'm reying to install cv blob lib in visual studio 2017, I saw tutorial on youtube. While trying program example, I get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The pointers are conditionally initialized in an if-statement starting at line 156:

```
if( maskImage )
{
    pMask = (unsigned char*) maskImage->imageData + j * maskImage->widthStep;
    // don't verify if we area on first or last row, it will verified on pointer access
    pAboveMask = (unsigned char*) maskImage->imageData + (j-1) * maskImage->widthStep;
    pBelowMask = (unsigned char*) maskImage->imageData + (j+1) * maskImage->widthStep;

}
```

So what happens when the if-statement is not entered, but the pointers are still used later in the code? Poof? Crash?

Comment: things that happen are still the same